# Re-generate random numbers in a loop

Tags: random, ocaml

I would like to create a basic genetic algorithm in order to output a set of input to enter in an emulator. Basically, what it does is :

- Generate an input sheet
- List item
- Run said input
- slightly modify it
- Run it
- See whichever input set performed better and "fork" it and repeat until the problem is solved

So : here is my code to generate the first set of inputs :

```
(* RNG initialization 
 * unit *)
Random.self_init();;


(* Generating a starting input file 
 * array 
 * 500 inputs long *)
let first_input =
let first_array = Array.make 500 "START" in
for i = 1 to 499 do
    let input = 
        match Random.int(5) with
        | 0 -> "A "
        | 1 -> "B "
        | 2 -> "DOWN "
        | 3 -> "LEFT "
        | 4 -> "RIGHT "
        | _ -> "START " in
    first_array.(i) <- input
done;
first_array;;
```

And here is my "mutation" function that randomly alters some inputs :

```
(* Mutating input_file 
 * Rate : in percent, must be positive and <= 100 
 * a must be an array of strings *)

let mutation a n=
let mutation_rate = n in
for i = 0 to ((Array.length(a) * mutation_rate / 100) - 1) do
    let input = 
        match Random.int(5) with
        | 0 -> "A "
        | 1 -> "B "
        | 2 -> "DOWN "
        | 3 -> "LEFT "
        | 4 -> "RIGHT "
        | _ -> "START " in
    a.( Random.int(498) + 1) <- input
done;;
```

However, I don't feel like my function is efficient because I had to paste the pattern matching part in the mutation function and I think there has to be a smarter way to proceed. If I define my "input" function as a global function, then it is only evaluated once (let's say as "RIGHT" and all occurrences of "input" will return "RIGHT" which is not really useful.

Thanks.

Comment: I might also suggest using polymorphic variants instead of the strings your using. It might make sense in the larger context to use strings, I don't know, but it's doubtful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with putting that into it's own function. What you are missing is an argument to make the function deal with the side-effect of `Random.int`. Since you are not using this argument, it's often/always the case people use `unit`.

```
   let random_input () = match Random.int 5 with
     | 0 -> "A "
     | 1 -> "B "
     | 2 -> "DOWN "
     | 3 -> "LEFT "
     | 4 -> "RIGHT "
     | _ -> "START "
```

What you are doing here is pattern matching the argument, and since there is only one constructor this matching is exhaustive. But technically, you can replace the `()` above with an `_`. This will match anything making the function polymorphic against it's argument, `'a -> string`. In this case it's bad form since it may lead to confusion as to what the parameter is for.